# How can i add a onchange js event to Select widget in Django?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-forms

I need to attach a JavaScript **onchange event** to the **receipt dropdown list** in a Django project. When the value of the dropdown list is changed a JavaScript function is to be called. How can it be done? The **form.py** file is given below

```
from django import forms
receipt_types=(('option1','Option 1'),('option2','Option 2'),('option3','Option 3'),)
class accountsInForm(forms.Form):
    receipt=forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.Select(choices=reciept_types))
```

Comment: JS functions are done on the frontend. Try to trigger the click event.

Comment: In the template file , the code for Select option is `{{receipt}}`. where should i add the js script.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change the code as follows :
 `reciept=forms.ChoiceField(reciept_types, widget = forms.Select(attrs = {'onchange' : "myFunction();"}))`

In case you want to have access to the input value in your JavaScript code, which is very common:

```
{'onchange' : "myFunction(this.value);"}
```

And the JS:

```
myFunction(value) {
    console.log(value)
}
```

Comment: if I have an external javascript file, with `myFunction` script, how would I correctly point it in forms.py?