# React on form changes

Tags: python, django, forms, django-admin, field

I have a general question to the django-admin.

Is it possible to react on form changes?

I have a select field in my django-admin detail site. Whenever I change the data from the select field, I want to change fields which are read-only.

Has anybody ever dealt with this issue?

Comment: which version of Django you are using ?

Comment: I think that you can do this with JavaScript, dude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My two cents:

As any other guys said it is a `javascript` work. In admin pages Django pases `jquery`. It is called `django.jQuery`. So basilly you would do what @Ashfaq suggested. You will create a `custom_script.js` and added to the `Media` metaclass.

Basically(as @Ashfaq):

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = ("js/custom_script.js",)
```

and `custom_script.js` will be something like this(assuming that your `select` field is called `id_category`):

```
django.jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    django.jQuery('#id_category').change(function() {
      alert( "Handler for #id_category was called." );
    });
});
```

The `ready` function will guarantee the handler is getting set.

Answer (score 2):

I think the thing that will work here is to add jQuery + your custom javascript and play with the events / clicks what-ever you want with elements.

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = ("js/custom_script.js",)
```

in custom_script you can add click or change events as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Found a great answer by Abhijith K in another SO Q&A:

[How can i add a onchange js event to Select widget in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46124531/how-can-i-add-a-onchange-js-event-to-select-widget-in-django/47103348)

```
reciept=forms.ChoiceField(reciept_types, widget = forms.Select(attrs = {'onchange': "myFunction();"}))
```

To be clear, this is what you add within your widget definition: `attrs = {'onchange': "myFunction();"}` to define which JS function will be called, in this when an `onchange` event is triggers.

In the ModelAdmin you can then define a JavaScript file that you want to have access to, where you can define your function "myFunction()":

```
@admin.register(AnswerTree)
class AnswerTreeAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    form = AnswerTreeForm
    ...

    class Media:
        js = ("admin_js/answertree_modeladmin.js",)
```

Django docs on defining assets (Like JavaScript & CSS) on your ModelAdmin:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-asset-definitions

What is also useful, I found out that you can access the value of the input by using `attrs = {'onchange': "myFunction(this.value);"}`, note that I am passing the argument `this.value` here now.

Example of the JavaScript function definition:

```
myFunction = (value) => {
    console.log(value)
}

OR

myFunction(value) {
    console.log(value)
}
```