# Invoke JavaScript function when the select element is first displayed

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have the following HTML in my Django app:

```
<select required size="1" name="relevancy" id="relevancy{{result.report_id}}" onChange="change_relevancy(this.value,{{ result.report_id }});">
<option value="" {% if result.relevance == " " %} selected {% endif %}>Select...</option>
<option value="N" {% if result.relevance == "N" %} selected {% endif %}>None</option>
<option value="M" {% if result.relevance == "M" %} selected {% endif %}>Moderate</option>
<option value="H" {% if result.relevance == "H" %} selected {% endif %}>High</option>
</select>
```

How do I call a JavaScript function when the select is first displayed?  I can detect when a user makes a selction, but not when the HTML makes the selection via the selected attribute.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i add a onchange js event to Select widget in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46124531/how-can-i-add-a-onchange-js-event-to-select-widget-in-django)

Comment: No, I can do that.  There's no user selection involved here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put a script tag with the appropriate function call after the select.  The function will execute when the html first loads, after the select is added to the DOM.

```
<select required size="1" name="relevancy" id="relevancy{{result.report_id}}" onChange="change_relevancy(this.value,{{ result.report_id }});">
<option value="" {% if result.relevance == " " %} selected {% endif %}>Select...</option>
<option value="N" {% if result.relevance == "N" %} selected {% endif %}>None</option>
<option value="M" {% if result.relevance == "M" %} selected {% endif %}>Moderate</option>
<option value="H" {% if result.relevance == "H" %} selected {% endif %}>High</option>
</select>

<script>callMyFunction()</script>
```